# How to send an eMail to all registered DSpace users?

Tags: email, dspace

Is it with DSpace possible to send an eMail to all registered users?
In the manual I only found 'dspace sub-daily' for sending users a message when a new document is submitted in the collection they have been subscribed for. 
But we like to reach all registered users.

Comment: I do not believe that this is possible.  I believe you would need to write a script to extract email addresses from the database in order to perform this action.

Comment: So I have to improve my Java skills, which are very very basic at the moment ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what DSpace version you are using (5.x or 6.x) you could use

- EPerson.findAll(context, sortField) -> For 5.x
- EPersonService.findAll(context, sortField) -> For 6.x

This will return an Array/List of EPerson objects, which you can use to call the "addRecipient" method of your newly created EMail object.

But, I would advice to be VERY careful doing this in terms of calling the mail sending because this could get very spammy, very fast.

Put it in a separate main class to use through the launcher so that the mail is only sent when required.

Comment: Thanks Jonas. Yes, I'm aware not sending to much eMails in one go. With a newsletter mailer I wrote in PHP eMails are sent in groups not larger then 250. That is working well.